# Proc IMPORT - csv files - avoid variables names as VARx

Tags: csv, import, sas, proc

After using `PROC IMPORT` I sometimes have in the dataset variable names as `VAR2` or `VAR3` ...(depending on the last column reading).
In the csv file, the column does indeed have a name which is not `"VARx"`.

How to avoid SAS producing the variable name as `"VARx"` in the `proc import` ?

```
proc import file = "location_of_file\file.csv"
   out = csv;
   dbms = csv REPLACE;
   guessingrows = 32767;
   getnames = yes;
run;

proc print data=csv;
run;


============================================
Obs ID NAME VAR3 
1   1  xxx  yyy 
2   2  zzz  aaa
```

The csv file contains column names as ID NAME and SURNAME.

Comment: Do your CSV files have a consistent structure? If so, you will probably get more consistent results if you write a data step to import them. Also, if you could provide some example data, people will be able to help you more easily.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the SAS documentation (e.g. http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/61895/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000312413.htm)

> If the column names in the first record in the input file are not valid SAS names, then the IMPORT procedure uses default variable names.